# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x

```
`HI I am trying to deploy ejb 2 project in jboss 7.1 and getting the NoClassDef found` `error of rt.jar . the detail error is as below.`
```

ERROR

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au/id/jericho/lib/html/Segment


at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]


at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]


at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]


at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>
```

(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at

org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentRefle
    ctionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 10 more`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Just add missed jar file to classpath here is link: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/htmlparser/jericho/jericho-html/2.6.1/jericho-html-2.6.1.jar